# Stream API, как получить среднее значение int для объекта в Коллекции?

Tags: java, spring, java-stream

Класс Employee имеет rоллекцию Reviews. Каждый Review имеет Grade.
Как получить cредний grade для Employee, используя Stream API?

```
@Entity
public class Employee extends AbstractBaseEntity {
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "employee",  cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Review> reviews;
}
@Entity
public class Review extends AbstractBaseEntity {
    private Byte grade;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функционалом [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#average--):

```java
    public class Employee  {
        private List<Review> reviews;

        public double avgGrade(){
            return reviews.stream()
                    .flatMapToInt(review-> IntStream.of(review.grade))
                    .average()
                    .orElse(0);
        }
    }
```